# How do I remove a mailbox from my modded world?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-mods

How do I remove a mailbox from MrCrayfish's Furniture Mod that has an owner? (I placed it under another name for the sake of realism) I tried removing it with commands yet it says there is no such item with ID Mail.

Comment: Do you mean the mailbox from Forestry? (there isn't one in vanilla)

Comment: Tt came with a mod I got called MrCrayfish's Furniture Mod.

Comment: I'm not familiar with that particular mod, but you should be able to remove it in creative mode.

Comment: I should be able to but I can't. It says I need administrators permission. Whatever that means.

Answer (score 3):

You need to right-click it with a hammer and then break it. If it's not right-clicking, it's shift-right-clicking.

Comment: I'll give that a shot. I've right clicked empty handed. Let's see how this works out.

Comment: what happened to this man?